# How to create a request that looks like this

Tags: c#, http, httpwebrequest

I need to replicate a HTTP request using C# and the HttpWebRequest, that looks like this:

> HEADER: POST /upnp/control/x_contact HTTP/1.1 Host: fritz.box:49000
>   Connection: Keep-Alive User-Agent:...

So far I got everything working, except for the part after the POST

"*/upnp/control/x_contact HTTP/1.1*".

How would I have to modify the HttpWebRequest to get these additional data to the server?

PS: This is how the java code looks, that generates the correct request. I would like to port this code to C# and send the same request from there:

```
socket = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName("fritz.box"), 49000);

// Send header
writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream(),"UTF-8"));
writer.write("POST /igdupnp/control/WANIPConn1 HTTP/1.1");
writer.write("Host: fritz.box:49000\r\n");
writer.write("SOAPACTION: \"urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:WANIPConnection:1#GetStatusInfo\"\r\n");
writer.write("Content-Type: text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\""+"\r\n");
writer.write("Content-Length: " + myData.length() + "\r\n");
writer.write("\r\n");

// Send data
writer.write(myData);

writer.flush();
```

And this is my C# code so far (producing an incomplete HTML request):

```
HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create (@"http://fritz.box:49000");

webRequest.Headers.Add ("SOAPACTION", "urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:WANIPConnection:1#GetStatusInfo");
webRequest.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"";
webRequest.Accept = "text/xml";
webRequest.Method = "POST";
```

Comment: Well thats the thing you're requesting and the http protocol you're using... so.... whats the problem

Comment: What do you mean by "thing you're requesting"? Like the URL? Ehen I add '/upnp/control/x_contact' as an appendix to my URL, the server does not like it (returns error). So there must be some other way to add the missing data to my request...

Comment: Well if you got to say "index.asp" then the thing might be "/index.asp" .. its whatever you're calling the other end....

Comment: The code I'm trying to convert (from Java to C#) did it differently. It always sent the request to "myserver.com" and then wrote "writer.write("POST  /upnp/control/x_contact HTTP/1.1");" to the request stream. Is this really the same as sending to "myserver.com/upnp/control/x_contact" directly?

Comment: As you've showed no code on how you're doing this. its hard to say for sure, but either way, the java way was doing it  directly, you maybe using bits of c# libraries to do it without seeing this directly.

Comment: I have added the original code that I would like to translate to C#.